# Css and html productive tools

Tags: html, css, developer-tools

I am beginning to learn css and html programming, 
I am currently using notepad to do it, 
Which IDE Tools provides automatic attributes listings to help code css and make css and html development more productive,
thanks,

Comment: StackOverflow is not a recommendation engine.

Comment: @Diodeus Don't you think that's rude? he need's help I guess..

Comment: Are we supposed to answer every question, even when not appropriate for this site? Go read the FAQ. There are other stack sites where this question would be appropriate, such as http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: If you want just a step up from Notepad, Notepad++ is a handy tool.

Comment: I usually agree with @Diodeus's first comment on these kinds of questions, however the FAQ does list "software tools commonly used by programmers" as one things generally allowed on the site. Either way, I don't think it was rude by any means.

Comment: @Diodeus Agreed but you should have mentioned that, anyways you didn't said anything wrong.

Comment: The problem with recommendations is that they are often subjective and are quickly out of a date. While these questions do have merit I don't think this is the right place for them.

Comment: @Diodeus ya got your point :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Aptana Studio 3](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3), it's free too..

Core Features :

- HTML, CSS, and JavaScript Code Assist
- Deployment Wizard
- Integrated Debugger
- Git Integration
- Built-in Terminal
- IDE Customization

Answer (score 2):

[Microsoft Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express) includes [intellisense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliSense) which is very useful when starting to learn HTML/CSS. It's also free to download.

Comment: Thanks, thumbs up for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I think if you're just beginning, you shouldn't be using an IDE. You'll rely on it too much and won't actually learn... then you'll never be able to do anything without the IDE.

That being said, I use [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/). The only feature I rely on is word complete since it auto completes every word, I don't accidentally mistype any variable names or anything. It also speeds up typing a lot since I usually only have to type out the first few characters of each word.

Last time I worked on a large project with someone else, we used Netbeans. It worked out pretty well for HTML, CSS, and PHP. Had version control built in, too.

I still default to Notepad++, though, because it's fast and simple. My point is, focus on learning and not the tools you're learning with. Once you are good enough at it, you can get tools to make development faster, but don't use them when you're beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I love dreamweaver for html css stuff. Other languages text mate is my favorite.